# Send to Messenger does not show up on my page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I have logged in fb account to have session.
I have whitelisted my domain.

I followed below as listed [in Send to Messenger Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/send-to-messenger-plugin)

```
(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.com/en_US/messenger.Extensions.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'Messenger'));
```

Then I have,

```
<div class="fb-send-to-messenger"
 messenger_app_id="xxx" #another question, is this same as the FB.init({appId: xxx})
 page_id="fb_page_id"
 data-ref="<PASS_THROUGH_PARAM>"
 color="blue"
 size="xlarge">
</div>
```

I already set up configurations in Facebook Developer page (see attached).

[image]

Comment: messenger_app_id="xxx" is the same as FB.init({appId: xxx})

If you are leaving <PASS_THROUGH_PARAM>, I dont think the <> is supported